# Browser returns 404 error when running Webpack dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I'm using Rails 6 with webpacker on a remote server.

When running `bin/webpack-dev-server`, it returns :

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://MY_HOST:3035/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /packs/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /PATH/public/packs
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html`
```

When visiting the URL, the pack URL returns a 404 error :

```
https://MY_HOST/packs/js/application-HASH.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

It works fine when I'm using `bin/webpack --watch`

Here is the dev_server configuration :

```rb
dev_server:
    https: true
    host: '0.0.0.0'
    port: 3035
    public: MY_HOST:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'
```

The `manifest.json` hashes are the same as what the webpack dev server generates.

I can't seem to understand what is the issue.

I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Is your browser developer console reporting CSP violations?

Comment: I don't see no violations. After reading more about webpack-dev-server, I think that the Rails app is catching the routes ? But I don't know how to get around it. Should I a create a none Rails app to serve the requests ? Should I proxy them ? I'm having a hard time grasping how the server behaves.

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Comment: It's been a while since I posted the question. I'm pretty sure that I fixed the issue but I don't remember what the problem was. I'll take a look and keep you updated.

Comment: Same issue with webpacker.

Comment: I create empty project with  
rails new myapp --webpack=react
and still have issue with webpack-dev-server

Comment: I have changed port in webpacker.yml to 3036 from 3035.   
And its work.   
I dont know why, there is no app on 3035 
lsof -i :3035